# Ubuntu 19.04 doesn't boot without a windows restart [on dual boot]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have an ASUS X456UB. I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04 on dual boot. Everytime I want to get into my Ubuntu, after putting in the password, the screen goes black and nothing happens after that. So I have found a fix for this, everytime I want to log in to Ubuntu, I have to do this:

1. Go to Windows 10.
2. Restart the PC from Windows 10.
3. Then try to log in to Ubuntu.

The above method always works. But it is a big hassle and annoying for me to log in to windows everytime I want to use ubuntu. I don't know the source of the problem nor the solution. I would love some help.

Comment: Are you properly shutting down or suspending?

Comment: Yeah. I think think this might be a hard drive issue?

Comment: The problem doesn't appear when I have suspended. The problem appears only when I have shutdown and want to access again @Fiximan

Comment: What happens if you logout first and then shut down?

Comment: @Fiximan, I can log into Ubuntu perfectly, without any issue. And also kindly excuse the late reply, I was away from my PC

Comment: Does CRTL+ALT+F1 let you go to a text mode TTY in case of the blackscreen?

Comment: No it does not @Fiximan

Comment: If it helps, I forgot to mention it earlier but if I wait for 20-30 mintes on the black screen, then some garbage message starts to print non stoply, it never stops. Earlier when I was using Ubuntu 16.10,  the same message used to print when booting, and I searched for it, the answer said that it was BIOS messages printing in time of booting. I forgot to mention this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if that could be because of Nvidia Optimus.
If yes, you could try to install "Prime"

First :

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee* primus libvdpau-va-gl1
```

Then :

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-**XXX** nvidia-prime mesa-utils
```

With **XXX** the most recent drivers in repository.